# Can't find Git using Version Control on R Studio after download

Tags: git, macos, github, rstudio

So I am a student enrolled at the University of Missouri.

I am enrolled in a course that uses R Studio daily and the professor has his class materials uploaded on a github account specific to our class.

He walked us through how to import the files from GitHub to R Studio using the procedure `File->New Project->Version Control->Git` and then supposedly I can paste his Git link into the next box to import the class materials/data into R Studio.

The Issue is that I have downloaded the latest Git from https://git-scm.com/downloads and proceeded to do the process described in the paragraph above. After I select "Version Control" and then select "Git" it appears a message that says the following:

"Git was not detected on the system path.

To create projects from Git repositories you should install Git and then restart RStudio

Note that if Git is installed and not on the path, then you can specify its location using the Preference dialog."

I did some research on this problem and found that I need to select Tools->Global Options->Git/Svn and then browse for something called /usr/local/git/bin or something along those lines. I can not seem to find that file. I have downloaded Git 2 or 3 times so there should be no issue with that. I have also restarted RStudio a few times like instructed. I have done research and attempted to work with the terminal but can't seem to solve this problem. I have a Mac with OS X version 10.9.5 and when installing Git I have selected the Macintosh Disk because that is my only option to store the installation. Answers would be great as I will begin falling behind in class soon without it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am on MacOS.

Under global options, the git path was set to `/usr/bin/git`, but this path was not valid.

```
$ /usr/bin/git

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and then retry this command.
```

So I dug around and figured out that Rstudio was looking on the path maintained by homebrew.

```
$ git --exec-path
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.23.0/libexec/git-core
```

So I set the git path to here in Rstudio:

[image]

And then I could configure git in the project options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path of your GIT to System Environment variables.

- Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System,
- and select the Advanced tab.
- Click Environment Variables. ...
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify
  the value of the PATH environment variable. ...
- create a new project as Git project

Comment: after setting the path in System Environment, you should create a new project ans choose Git project, then you will see it!